# How to void a payment in netsuite using netsuite webservice

Tags: void, netsuite

I need to void a payment made in netsuite by using NetSuite webservice. Is it possible? I have tried by adding Journal entry for the payment which i need to void. But it doesn't work for me. Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using suite scripts you can use

```
nlapiVoidTransaction(transactionType, recordId);
```

This API is supported in the following script types:

```
Client
User Event
Scheduled
Suitelet
RESTlet
Workflow Action
```

The Governance on this API is 10.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule in Netsuite webservice is, if it can be done in the user-interface then it can be done via webservices.

By voiding you mean, deleting the payment? If you can confirm that it is possible do to it (no other child records attach on it, etc.) then it can be done via webservices.

Comment: Voding doen't mean deleting the payment.It changes the state of payment as void and the payment amount is credited into debit account back.In netsuite UI we have Void button which affects the record as follows, It create the journal entry for the payment and change the status of payment as void

Comment: You can't delete the payment cause it is linked to other transaction record.

Answer (score 0):

Voiding is not supported via web services or SuiteScript.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this statement, I'm currently trying to figure out a way to void a sales order. But if it isn't possible I'd like to see it in its definitive form. Many Thanks.