# How to void/cancel a Payment on Netsuite by Suitetalk

Tags: c#, netsuite

I need to implement a function to Void/Cancel a VendorPayment on Netsuite by SuiteTalk.

I've spent a day for researching it but no help, no document, nothing :(

This is the only link that I founded but no help
[How to void a payment in netsuite using netsuite webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536205/how-to-void-a-payment-in-netsuite-using-netsuite-webservice)

Comment: How can I contact with @SuiteResource ? I think he can help me.
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1807800/suite-resources?tab=profile

Answer (score 1):

Using Suite script basically you can use

```
nlapiVoidTransaction(transactionType, recordId);
```

Not sure, if is there any equivalent method of this in Suitetalk presently. I haven't much grab my hands on `C#` though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not cancel the payment from webservice, I leave the manual of version 2016.2 in it contain everything if possible via suitetalk

https://system.na2.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/PDF/SuiteTalkWebServicesPlatformGuide.pdf